# SQL Invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, addition, alter-table

With the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE USERS
    ADD LAST_LOGIN DATETIME()
```

I am receiving the error below:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why SQLDeveloper does not like the fromatting of my rather simple alter table command.

Comment: Can you try DATETIME without the parentheses?

Comment: That gives me: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Are you sure your version of oracle has a datetime datatype?

Comment: hmm, if not would there be a way to add one? I would think it would throw me an invalid datatype error if that was the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATETIME` is not a valid column data type.  If you're trying to add a default value, you need to specify a [`DEFAULT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAFIJBC).

If you are trying to use a date format, please use one of the [datetime or interval data types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#sthref389).  If you need to store date and time, the standard `DATE` format stores year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds.